# Objective C class problem

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a Class object in this way:
Class c = [Class classNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%sview", [_shapeClass name]]];

My problem is this error message: "error: expected expression before 'Class'".
What do you think? What's the problem? Thank you for replys.

Edit:
I want to do this in a switch case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class named "Class". "Class" is the type of a pointer to a class object. Anyway, there is a `classNamed:` method in `NSBundle`, which might be what you were looking for:

```
Class c = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%sview", [_shapeClass name]]];
```

If you know the class is already loaded, you can also get it like this:

```
Class c = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%sview", [_shapeClass name]]);
```

Comment: When will a class in `[NSBundle mainBundle]` ever not be loaded?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there's no such class as Class (and as a side note, this nonexistent class also doesn't respond to `classNamed:`).

It's not quite clear whether you want to *create* a class or get a *reference* to a class. If the latter, you want the function `NSClassFromString()`. If you want to dynamically create a class at runtime, you'll need to use the [Objective-C runtime functions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) to create a class, register it and add methods as appropriate.