# Retrieving a Class by String using NSBundle -classNamed: fails in iOS10

Tags: ios-simulator, ios10

I discovered problems on iOS 10, where a viewcontroller with a string generated classname is not loaded. The issue occured on iPad Air 2, when users launch the app for the second time (after closing it hard).

In the simulator with Xcode 8 the error is reproducable. It seems that the viewcontroller could not be instantiated and that this code does not work anymore. Is this right?

```
Class controllerClass = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:className];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a simple switch case structure to create the controllers. It needs more lines of code, but it´s safer code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that uses the underlying Objective-C function **objc_getClass()** and ignores the now (since iOS10?) buggy method of NSBundle. As this function does the same as [MyClass class] it should not be able to fail.

Old versions (iOS8 and older) of my App using this code seem to fail on new hardware, too.  It looks like the faster the device is the more likely the method will fail. For me the fail rate of the iOS Simulator is about 50%.

```
    id objc_getClass(const char *name); // define the function signature without importing it
    Class cls = objc_getClass([s cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    NSAssert(cls != nil, @"classNamed: %@ returned nil!", s);
```

References

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/200857
- [NSClassFromString() vs classNamed:(NSString *)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524165/nsclassfromstring-vs-classnamednsstring)
- [Objective C class problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816712/objective-c-class-problem)